# Excel comment invisible under cell

Tags: excel, ms-office, comments, office-2003

My excel comment is gone under the cell ...how to make it always on top?

Comment: red flag is not visible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right-click the cell with the comment and choose 'Show/Hide comment' might do the trick

Comment: nooo... that is only for editing ..after editing it again  gone inside the cell :-(

Comment: there is an 'edit comment' option and a show/hide option. they do different things.